# samba share but sub folders are not readable

Tags: samba

I want to share a folder with samba. I want the folder to be read only and I don't want the user to have to enter a username or password.

I add the configuration to my smb.conf file and the folder is exposed as a share. The problem is I cannot access any folders below that directory.

What is the easiest way to allow the user to see the shared folders and the files below the folder?

Comment: You should begin with copying your smb.conf here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the filespermission for the diretory to 774.
`chmod -R 774 your_directory`

Then set the guest user in the `[global]` section and enable the share in smb.conf.

```
security = share  
guest account = nobody
```

Now create the share

```
[your_share]  
comment = your share access  
path = /path_to_share  
browseable = yes  
read only = yes  
guest ok = yes
```